# Compiler Error: error: ‘ListNode’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am trying to write my class and struct implementation files. The class has variables from the struct. I keep getting the errors:

LinkedList.h:70:8: error: ‘ListNode’ does not name a type
        ListNode* head;

LinkedList.h:71:8: error: ‘ListNode’ does not name a type
        ListNode* cursor;

LinkedList.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef CLASS_LINKEDLIST_H
#define CLASS_LINKEDLIST_H

// Header files 

#include <iostream>
#include "ListNode.h"

using namespace std;

class LinkedList 
   {
    public:
    LinkedList( int maxSize = 10 );
    LinkedList( const LinkedList& other );
    ~LinkedList();

    private:

       ListNode* head;
       ListNode* cursor;

       int capacity;
       int size;
   };

#endif // ifndef CLASS_LINKEDLIST
```

ListNode.h is a struct like this:

```
#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_H

using namespace std;

struct ListNode
   {
     ListNode( int nodeData, ListNode* nextPtr);
     int dataItem;
     ListNode* next;
   };
#endif  // STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

ListNode.cpp looks like this:

```
#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_H

#include "ListNode.h"
#include <iostream>

ListNode:: ListNode(int nodeData, ListNode* nextPtr)
   { 
     dataItem = nodeData;
     next = nextPtr;
   }

#endif // STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

And here is the top of LinkedList.cpp

```
#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_H

// header files
#include "LinkedList.h"
```

I am not allowed to change the .h files, just the .cpp ones. I know there is something simple that I am forgetting to include, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why does *LinkedList.cpp* have include guards?  Is it included by another file?

Comment: Yep, remove the include guards from your CPP files.  Include guards are usually the lines that say `#ifndef filename_h`.

Comment: Is this homework and you were given the header files? If so it is worrying that they have `using namespace std;` in the headers... `using namespace` in headers is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the include guards from the CPP files and it got rid of the error. So those are only supposed to go on .h files?

Comment: @jake415 yes, since only headers ever get included by other files. The guards just make sure a file doesn't get include twice. Normally since nothing is requiring the cpp, you don't need guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include guard are placed so that if a file winds up being included multiple times, it only is used once.

When you include a file, it is, for all intents and purposes, copy-pasted into the including file, so to the compiler's pre-processor, ListNode.cpp looks like this:

```
#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_H

#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_H

using namespace std;

struct ListNode
   {
     ListNode( int nodeData, ListNode* nextPtr);
     int dataItem;
     ListNode* next;
   };
#endif  // STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#include <iostream> //contents of iostream go on for pages. Let's skip those, shall we?

ListNode:: ListNode(int nodeData, ListNode* nextPtr)
   { 
     dataItem = nodeData;
     next = nextPtr;
   }

#endif // STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

Breaking that down the compiler sees:

```
#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

If STRUCT_LISTNODE_H has not been defined, do everything up until the corresponding `#endif`.

```
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

Cool. STRUCT_LISTNODE_H  has just been defined.

```
#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

This time STRUCT_LISTNODE_H has been defined, so we skip down to the corresponding endif:

```
#endif  // STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

That's right, the header file was almost completely discarded. So what's going to be compiled is:

```
#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_H

#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#endif  // STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
#include <iostream> //contents of iostream go on for pages. Let's skip those, shall we?

ListNode:: ListNode(int nodeData, ListNode* nextPtr)
   { 
     dataItem = nodeData;
     next = nextPtr;
   }

#endif // STRUCT_LISTNODE_H
```

There is no no sign of `ListNode`'s definition.

So this isn't so much that OP used include guards in a cpp file (and a cpp file should never be included, so include guards are unnecessary), but that OP used the same include guard twice.

As a public service announcement, the usual warning about `using namespace std;`
That evil little shortcut pulls the entire standard library into the global namespace. That means if you had a function named `reverse`, it now has to fight it out with `std::reverse` and you may not like who wins and what that does to your program's execution.

So OK. Your code is just fine with that, but what if you include someone else's? Now they are conflicting with names they didn't intend and you have weird error messages they've never even seen and probably can't help you with.

Use it sparingly. Either prefix with std::

```
std::cout << "HI!" << std::endl;
```

or only pull the pieces you need into the global namespace

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

and later

```
cout << "HI!" << endl;
```

Most importantly do this last after including everyone else's header files because you don't know how they will respond. But that is your problem for being lazy. Sucks to be you.

And that brings us to why you don't put `using namespace std;` in a header. Some poor sucker includes your header to use your library. WHAM! They inherit your bad coding style. They suffer for your mistakes. That is not cool.